# Python patch of a object creation not working

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

**app.py**

```
class UnderTest:
    def one(self):
        print('In one')
        email = EmailSender(None, 'messwage');
        email.send()
```

**EmailSender.py**

```
class EmailSender:
    def __init__(self, config, message):
        self.mess = message;

    def send(self):
        print("should not be invoked")
```

**test_under_test.py**

```
class test_under_test(TestCase):

    @patch('EmailSender.EmailSender')
    def test_one(self, email):
        test = UnderTest()
        email.send.return_value = None;
        test.one();
```

The 'send' method of the EmailSender should not have invoked, but, it is being invoked. When i debug instead of the Mock object in the `email` variable in EmailSender.one method i see original object of EmailSender, the patch is not working as expected here. what should I do?

Comment: `@patch('app.EmailSender')`. See [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).